# Java 7 sorting "optimisation"

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

In Java6 both quicksort and mergesort were used in `Arrays#sort`, for primitive and object arrays respectively.  In Java7 these have both changed, to [DualPivotQuicksort](http://www.cyberwart.com/blog/2009/09/11/quicksort-beaten/) and Timsort.

In the source for the new quicksort, the following comment appears in a couple of places (eg line 354):

```
 /*
  * Here and below we use "a[i] = b; i++;" instead
  * of "a[i++] = b;" due to performance issue.
  */
```

How is this a performance issue?  Won't the compiler will reduce these to the same thing?

More broadly, what is a good strategy for investigating this myself?  I can run benchmarks, but I'd be more interested in analysing any differences in the compiled code.  However, I don't know what tools to use etc.

Comment: Either the hotspot compiler has done something wrong (unlikely) or the ones who wrote the microbenchmark screwed it... and I bet on the latter. (there are many small reasons why some code may appear to outperform another - like memory pages, environment size and what not)

Comment: @bestsss Always possible of course, but the guys who wrote this code (and subsequently the comment) *do* know how to write a benchmark. After all, the Java quicksort implementation has been benchmarked and fine-tuned to death.

Comment: FYI, the attributed @authors of this class are Josh Bloch, Jon Bentley (author of Programming Pearls), and Vladimir Yaroslavskiy

Comment: @Konrad, you will surprised yourself, you if try to look up the history of the microbenchmarks and how they have influenced java (one of them made the way of AtomicLong). There have been a lot of mistake going there; some weird fixes (incl. intrinsic fixes in the JVM and so on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only an answer to the general question.

You can look at the bytecode and try to understand the differences. I.e. you could write yourself a simple example using both `a[i] = b; i++;` and `a[i++] = b;` and see whats the difference.

The simplest way to show the bytecode is the `javap` program (should be included in you JDK). Compile the code with `javac SomeFile.java` and run javap on the code: `javap -c SomeFile` (the -c switch tells javap to output the bytecode for each method in the file).

If you are using eclipse you could also try [this one](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html).

Comment: Thanks - this plugin does show that the generated bytecode is not the same.  Now to read up on how to read bytecode!

Comment: I’m not sure how definitive looking at the bytecode is. After all, most of the optimisations take place in the JIT. I’d go further: the bytecode in this case is entirely irrelevant, and this answer is misleading.

Comment: Thanks to the many optimizations that HotSpot does, looking only at the bytecode won't gieve many clues as to the expected performance after jitting.

Comment: At least if the bytecodes were the same we could say that JIT wouldn't make a difference...

Answer (score 5):

I wrote 2 methods *test1* and *test2* and add the main part of the compiled byte code (Java 1.6 on Snow Leopard) as comment:

```
    /*
     *     14  iload_1 [b]      -> load value from address 1 to sack
     *     15  iastore          -> store value from stack into int array
     *     16  iinc 3 1 [i]     -> int increment value of address 3
     *     19  iinc 3 1 [i]     -> int increment value of address 3
     */
    public void test1() {
        int b = 0;
        int a[] = new int[10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            a[i] = b; 
            i++;
        }
    }

    /*
     *     14  iinc 3 1 [i]     -> increment value of address 3
     *     17  iload_1 [b]      -> load value from address 1 to stack
     *     18  iastore          -> store value from stack into int array
     *     19  iinc 3 1 [i]     -> increment value of address 3 
     */
    public void test2() {
        int b = 0;
        int a[] = new int[10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            a[i++] = b;
        }
    }
```

The order of the `inc` ops is different. But the operation sum of both methods *test1* and *test2* are equal! So the byte codes performance should be the same, too.

Comment: It is conceivable that an optimizer may optimize two consecutive inc calls into one add $reg, 2 call (which I think should be faster at least on x86?) which is a whole lot harder for the second variant - still doable, but maybe Hotspots current optimizations don't?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way that allows you to see the [processor instructions generated by the hotspot engine](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly).

Comment: I would love to hear the name of that tool - that'd be extremely useful or at least interesting.

Comment: @Voo, it's not a too, it's a hotspot option. http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly  yet the best way to check it is just attaching the gdb.