# Most efficient way to create an array of counting numbers

Tags: java, arrays, performance

What's the most efficient way to make an array of a given length, with each element containing its subscript?

Possible description with my dummy-level code:

```
/**
 * The IndGen function returns an integer array with the specified dimensions.
 *  
 *  Each element of the returned integer array is set to the value of its 
 *  one-dimensional subscript.
 *  
 *  @see Modeled on IDL's INDGEN function: 
 *      http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/INDGEN.html 
 *  
 *  @params size
 *  @return int[size], each element set to value of its subscript
 *  @author you
 *  
 *  */

public int[] IndGen(int size) {
    int[] result = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) result[i] = i;
    return result;
}
```

Other tips, such as doc style, welcome.

### Edit

I've read elsewhere how inefficient a `for` loop is compared to other methods, as for example in [Copying an Array](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=3):

> Using clone: 93 ms
>
> Using System.arraycopy: 110 ms
>
> Using Arrays.copyOf: 187 ms
>
> Using for loop: 422 ms

I've been impressed by the imaginative responses to some questions on this site, e.g., [Display numbers from 1 to 100 without loops or conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions). Here's an answer that might suggest some methods:

```
public class To100 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String set = new java.util.BitSet() {{ set(1, 100+1); }}.toString();
        System.out.append(set, 1, set.length()-1);
    }
}
```

**If you're not up to tackling this challenging problem,** no need to vent: just move on to the next unanswered question, one you can handle.

Comment: That seems to work. Please don't micro-optimize.

Comment: who asked you to optimize this code?

Comment: How large _is_ this array? Are we talking megabytes or gigabytes of data here?

Comment: The true question is: What do you want to do with that array? You'll have a very hard time making this code significantly faster, so maybe you should think about what you actually need it for.

Comment: Do you really need an array?  You could make a very efficient iterable, here.

Comment: @sarnold, not clear at this point. It may be 10^12 elements, or more. Very demanding application.

Comment: So you need 3.6 Terabytes of integers. What happens at element `2147483648`? Should the integer wrap back to `0`, or `-2147483647`, or are you going to be storing these in 64-bit integer fields? (Which would take 7 terabytes of data.)

Comment: @Cole: That's almost always excellent advice, but the problem at hand involves three to seven terabytes of data. Every microoptimization is probably worth exploring.

Comment: @DarthVader, actually it was Obi Wan.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's infeasible to use terabytes of memory at once, and especially to do any calculation with them simultaneously, you might considering using a generator.  (You were probably planning to loop over the array, right?)  With a generator, you don't need to initialize an array (so you can start using it immediately) and almost no memory is used (O(1)).

I've included an example implementation below.  It is bounded by the limitations of the `long` primitive.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Counter implements Iterator<Long> {
    private long count;
    private final long max;

    public Counter(long start, long endInclusive) {
        this.count = start;
        this.max = endInclusive;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return count <= max;
    }

    @Override
    public Long next() {
        if (this.hasNext())
            return count++;
        else
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Find a usage demonstration below.

```
Iterator<Long> i = new Counter(0, 50);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i.next());  // Prints 0 to 50
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but it is highly educational. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

only thing i ca think of is using "++i" instead of "i++" , but i think the java compiler already has this optimization .

other than that, this is pretty much the best algorithm there is.

you could make a class that acts as if it has an array yet it doesn't , and that it will simply return the same number that it gets (aka the identity function) , but that's not what you've asked for.

Comment: That only makes a difference for c++ and complex objects. For anything else any compiler will generate identical code for a single expression. Apart from your proposal for a lazy class there's really nothing we can do. Well SSE could be used (not in java..) but the code's so clearly memory limited that I can't see how that would really help.

Comment: here is something related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676836/java-7-sorting-optimisation/6677341#6677341 and its like Voo says, there is no real difference

Answer (score 0):

As other have said in their answers, your code is already close to the most efficient that I can think of, at least for small sized arrays. If you need to create those arrays a lot of times and they are very big, instead of continuously iterating in a for loop you could create all the arrays once, and then copy them. The copy operation will be faster than iterating over the array if the array is very big. It would be something like this (in this example for a maximum of 1000 elements):

```
public static int[][] cache = {{0},{0,1},{0,1,2},{0,1,2,3},{0,1,2,3,4}, ..., {0,1,2,...,998,999}};
```

Then, from the code where you need to create those arrays a lot of times, you would use something like this:

```
int[] arrayOf50Elements = Arrays.copyOf(cache[49], 50);
```

Note that this way you are using a lot of memory to improve the speed. I want to emphasize that this will only be worth the complication when you need to create those arrays a lot of times, the arrays are very big, and maximum speed is one of your requirements. In most of the situations I can think of, the solution you proposed will be the best one.

**Edit:** I've just seen the huge amount of data and memory you need. The approach I propose would require memory of the order of n^2, where n is the maximum integer you expect to have. In this case that's impractical, due to the monstrous amount of memory you would need. Forget about this. I leave the post because maybe it is useful for others.

Comment: while this is in no way a knock on your original response, i find it amsuing to picture a line of code that initializes 3.6TB worth of integers.   :)